# How do you select a rectangular block of numbers in the Joe editor?

Tags: joe-editor

I'm using the Joe editor (http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/index.html) and want to know how to select a rectangular block of numbers. I know how to select text with ^KB and ^KK but when I do that for a column of numbers, it selects the entire row. For an image of what I'm talking about please see http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/elaborate.gif and look at the bottom of the image in the 'Size' column.

My goal is to perform Joe commands on a column of numbers such as sum, cnt, avg, dev (http://joe-editor.sourceforge.net/list.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## To select a rectangle block:

Switch to 'Rectangle mode' with ^TX.

Mark the top left corner of the block ot ^KB.

Use arrow keys to navigate to the lower right corner of the block.
Mark lower right corner with ^KK.

Selected block can now be used with math functions.

## To sum the selected rectangle block:

Enter Math mode with ESC M.

Type `=sum`.

Result is displayed in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> when selecting.

Comment: That works to copy text to the clipboard. But I asked how to select a column of text so that the selected text goes into a buffer in Joe. Then I'll be able to run Joe commands such as 'sum' to get the sum of a column of values.

Answer (score 0):

For Joe versions 3.7+, the option is now `^Tsquare`, not `^TX` anymore.